# Array assignment only works with intermediate variable in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, variable-assignment, stdvector

I have a weird problem where an array assignment only works if I use an intermediate variable. Here's the setup of the program:

```
struct A {
    int values[4];
};

std::vector<A> items;
```

The `items` vector is inside a class, defined in its header file. The vector is filled with 'A' structs during class construction. The `values` array is left as is. In a function in the .cpp file, the code to fill in the `values` array is as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) {
    items[i].values[0] = 0;
    for(int j=1; j<4; j++) {
        items[i].values[j] = getValue(); // returns an int
        cout << items[i].values[j] << endl; // prints -1 for index 1 and 2
    }
}
```

If instead I change the inner loop to the following, it works correctly:

```
    for(int j=1; j<4; j++) {
        int val = getValue(); // returns an int
        items[i].values[j] = val;
        cout << items[i].values[j] << endl; // prints correct value
    }
```

I checked the `getValue` function, it appears to be working correctly. Here's the code for it:

```
int getValue() {
    items.push_back(A()); // just adds a new 'A' object to the vector
    return items.size() - 1;
}
```

Does it have something to do with the fact that the `items` vector is modified during the `push_back` call, which somehow invalidates the left-hand side of the `items[i].values[j] = getValue();` statement? From what I can tell, there aren't any memory issues elsewhere in the code.

**Additional Info:** 
I posted a watered-down version of the code, but this is basically exactly what it's doing. The 'A' struct has a few more variables inside that get allocated. Also, this code runs correctly on OS X, but fails on Linux. Using gcc/++ 4.4.7.

Comment: Your suspicion about modification is correct. The code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your non-working code exhibits undefined behavior. Evaluation of `items[i]` is indeterminately sequenced with that of `getValue()`. If it happens to be evaluated first, it produces a reference to a vector element which may be invalidated by the subsequent `push_back` on that same vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it have something to do with the fact that the items vector is
>   modified during the push_back call, which somehow invalidates the
>   left-hand side of the
>   `items[i].values[j] = getValue();` statement?

Yes, it does.

The sides of an assignment aren't determinately sequenced, so the code has undefined behaviour.

These are very hard bugs to track down, but the "feature" allows some low-level optimizations.
For instance, if the function call is inlined, the computations on the left and right sides can be interleaved, minimising stalls.